# Chemical sentences! Encrypting

Tags: code-golf, string, chemistry

## Background

You are bored in class, and having exhausted all the possible things to write on a standard calculator (Like 8008135) you turn to the periodic table. You want to figure out if you can write your message using the shorthand for chemical elements.

*This is the inverse of [this challenge.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/64862/8478)*

[image]

## The Challenge

**Input**: A sentence, or a word.

**Output**: The placement of each chemical element used in the sentence. 
If the sentence / word can not be created, you must return blank, False or throw an error.

**Test cases**
Input 1:

```
fire
```

Output 1:

```
9 53 75
```

Input 2:

```
Crazy Input
```

Output 3:

```
False
```

Input 3:

```
american ass
```

Output 3:

```
95 68 53 20 11 16 16
```

Note: There is no problem with a element being in two words as shown in the last example. American can be written as `95 68 53 20 7` but then `Ass` is impossible to write due to the lack of an A in the table. In other words discard all whitespaces (but they must be allowed) in input.

**Note** Standard loopholes are not allowed including built in periodic tables and libraries.

## Scoring

Submissions will be scored in **bytes**. I recommend [this website](http://bytesizematters.com) to keep track of your byte count, though you can use any counter you like.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the lowest score wins!

Comment: Is the use of periodic table built-ins allowed?

Comment: I forgot Mathematica had such capabilities! On one hand this gives and advantage to a very few select languages, on the other hand hardcoding these will be a pain. Being the more experienced what do you think @Dennis?

Comment: Encoding the table is the biggest part of the challenge, so a built-in table would, in my opinion, trivialize it for some languages. Personally, I'd disallow them.

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6284/8478)

Comment: Yes. Updated it now.