# Ambiguous Chemical Formula

Tags: code-golf, string, chemistry

If you convert a chemical formula to lower case, it may become ambiguous: `co` can be both `CO` or `Co`.

Given an input consisting of `a-z0-9`, where `0` can only stand behind `0-9`. Check whether it's ambiguous, unambiguous, or impossible. Return 3 different values for them. Shortest code wins.

Examples:

```
co     - ambiguous
2h83o6 - unambiguous
li     - unambiguous
l      - impossible
cli    - ambiguous
c10h7o - unambiguous
```

One-sentence meaning: Is there zero, one or multiple ways to split input into concatenation of the following strings, case insensitive:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,H,He,Li,Be,B,C,N,O,F,Ne,Na,Mg,Al,Si,P,S,Cl,Ar,K,Ca,Sc,Ti,V,Cr,Mn,Fe,Co,Ni,Cu,Zn,Ga,Ge,As,Se,Br,Kr,Rb,Sr,Y,Zr,Nb,Mo,Tc,Ru,Rh,Pd,Ag,Cd,In,Sn,Sb,Te,I,Xe,Cs,Ba,La,Ce,Pr,Nd,Pm,Sm,Eu,Gd,Tb,Dy,Ho,Er,Tm,Yb,Lu,Hf,Ta,W,Re,Os,Ir,Pt,Au,Hg,Tl,Pb,Bi,Po,At,Rn,Fr,Ra,Ac,Th,Pa,U,Np,Pu,Am,Cm,Bk,Cf,Es,Fm,Md,No,Lr,Rf,Db,Sg,Bh,Hs,Mt,Ds,Rg,Cn,Nh,Fl,Mc,Lv,Ts,Og
```

## Notes

- You need to code the table into your program, since as I searched there was no question requiring an unordered chemical element table.

Comment: _Given an input consisting of `a-z0-9`_ ~> So the input may contain `j` or `q` even if they're not used in any symbol, right?

Comment: Most of the byte count is going to be that long string (or a variation thereof, possibly compressed), rather than the actual code. This makes the challenge less interesting, and is in fact an archetype of [chameleon challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8214/36398). For similar challenges in the future, consider taking the string as an input

Comment: Wait... how is `2h83o6` unambiguous in the test cases? Surely this could be decomposed to `2h8` `3o6` or `2h` `83o6` or `2h83` `o6`?

Comment: @KinuTheDragon What's `2H8 3O6`?

Comment: @l4m2 I meant that `2h83o6` could possibly be reordered to have `2h8` `3o6` in the chemical formula instead of the other forms. Basically, is a multi-digit number ambiguous? (e.g. 83 could be split 8 and 3)

Comment: @KinuTheDragon I haven't seen `2H8 3O6` though I've seen `2H8.3O6`, but `.` is not in input

Comment: @l4m2 Ok, so multi-digit numbers are unambiguous when between two elements?

Comment: `as I searched there was no question requiring an unordered chemical element table.` but then it marked [a related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/112608/) that do so

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 265 bytes

*Saved 6 bytes thanks to @tsh*

Expects an array of characters. Returns **0** for *unambiguous*, **1** for *ambiguous*, or **-1** for *impossible*.

```javascript
s=>s.reduce((p,c,i)=>p|=1/c||b?b=0:/[bcfhiknopsuvwy]/.test(c)+(b=/([ace][rsu]|[cgn][ade]|[iz][nr]|a[cglmt]|b[aehikr]|c[fl-o]|d[bsy]|f[elmr]|h[efgos]|kr|l[airuv]|m[cdgnot]|n[bhiop]|o[gs]|p[abdmortu]|r[abe-hnu]|s[bcegimnr]|t[abcehilms]|xe|yb)$/.test(c+s[i+1]))-1,b=0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY/NTsMwEITvPEVVcUjUJmlBAoSU8iArH@zNJjF1vFGclBb53cvyU4lDBa1Po9HnmdlXvdMBB9uPmeeKjnV5DOUm5ANVE1KS9Etc2rTc9LFcFxijeTHl6rkAg3Vrt577MO3eDqrIRwpjgukiMWWRgEZSMIRJRcDGK9AVibTvCvygohbTdaOKBjRJjFgItctYxQpMOKhYA7lO7BaobjiouB2iA22HaadiB1g1nuW/B9Na7lVkaATqQZuq42GU3kE0Za0XGWQtNbb7rB7FRul0nfB7igeT3p7GLwLYxVqlabZeypXpEdkHdpQ7bpI6gTzP58jzmTyBZkUx052xzcRTuDmD3rVP9/ww/0En/yfs7O/c/@Av9gTbrucQrHF0jsXv5EsG43rVPvKFg/d0xeA90fzSwYxXBCPvzwYfPwA)

### How?

The variable \$p\$ holds the final result. The flag \$b\$ is set whenever a 2-character chemical symbol is matched.

For each character \$c\$ at position \$i\$ in the input array:

- If \$c\$ is a digit or the flag \$b\$ is set, we clear \$b\$ and leave \$p\$ unchanged.
- Otherwise, we compute:

  ```javascript
  p |= /E1/.test(c) + (b = /E2/.test(c + s[i + 1])) - 1
  ```

  where `/E1/` and `/E2/` are regular expressions matching 1-character and 2-character chemical symbols respectively.

  Which leads to:

  ```
   /E1/ matching | /E2/ matching | sum - 1 | meaning
  ---------------+---------------+---------+------------
   no            | no            |   -1    | impossible
   no            | yes           |    0    | unchanged
   yes           | no            |    0    | unchanged
   yes           | yes           |    1    | ambiguous
  ```

Comment: `i[nr]|...|z[nr]` -> `[iz][nr]`

Comment: `a[cglmr-u] ... c[adefl-orsu] ... e[rsu]` -> `a[cglmt] ... c[adefl-o] ... [ace][rsu]`

Comment: `c[adefl-o] ... g[ade] ... n[abdehiop]` -> `c[fl-o] ... [cgn][ade] ... n[bhiop]`

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 194 bytes

```
“×ĿcṚ¦mßṛy|3¹,GƊ§ḋCƤṂỴƇƈÇ¡ɱɓkȷ¶ʂạ⁺ịọ9ėżḣ÷8ÆC⁼³°0|KṪƈŀ@:ḤvƥÄƭsɲẸpI0⁷tÞO§ƒ;ḷ8ḟhıA€ḊṪḷ`ɦḊa¥IƭịƤñ¡÷?²ạ©œ5EẏṢɲ⁺ȷɗL4Q¤F⁹~Ṿ⁸ṪṄ|eėgṖ€ṂɠƲ2ʂ⁺ɱḌḳWƘɠṛ;⁵2nȦƝ]ṇUṆ84¥ẸṪḲdþ¹Ẋd©’ṃØẠØD;µe€ØD;ØA¤œṗ
¢Œl⁸ŒṖ¤e€€ȦƇL«2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY9bSwJREMff@xThcw9mN8uHim5EQfQQPQWFSVaWQREEEu4WbVgRKLR211qNbpB22XPWKJjjHjx9izlfZDtbMAz/GWZ@85@lWCKx5XkyfcHM@ncU6RmUV9g10vOtVBvQlhGegTskBwPcQqpj7Y0bfJ8ZUBQVkVtu2PDxo6NTlJqDtQOsHXXXTfcTyS2zw2xvQGqf8AovwdQY0ge@76b7epBYm7zEdvnzuqiiQ9ZGg1KzN9jVBNzxbASJHUZyHa9X@qX@hCSjFlVvVpSVnoPSKH9Wh7jFKlBkdi8oRBHu3VzHEDrHSG9EVVlp2MIcb58Ea1hqdBvpl9SIz6G7qVjdXEB64rOpLgq8GvrR1YaoIDlE8jrN86Kgno9I7T202ijzyxmkxhTSvXA7lJTdPzvVefYFFJ3MPNzL9CnSHZZHp8DygxF4jym2r1i@Hyw3h9Rsghs3m1Ae3Kw6DZY/oULRjXF4DHnMUJXnBaLJQEtzIBQPtyU7fZVY/Mt@iv7raGsw3pUM/AI)

-2 bytes thanks to caird coinheringaahing via better usage of chaining

Output 2 for ambiguous, 1 for unambiguous, 0 for impossible.

The logic behind this is pretty trivial, I just need to figure out a better way of encoding this periodic table...

```
“...’ṃØẠØD;µe€ØD;ØA¤œṗ  Helper Link; produce the list of components
“...’                   Compressed Integer
     ṃØẠ                Base-decoded into the upper and lower-case alphabet
        ØD;             Prepend the digits (as strings) as well
           µ            With the list of components (joined on nothing) as the left argument
            e€          Check if each element is in
              ØD;ØA¤    The digits + uppercase alphabet
                    œṗ  And partition the components before those indices

¢Œl⁸ŒṖ¤e€€ȦƇL«2         Main Link
¢Œl                     The components above, lowercased
   ⁸ŒṖ¤                 All ways of partitioning the input
         €              For each partition
        €               For each component
       e                Is it in the list of valid components?
          ȦƇ            Filter to keep partitions where every component was valid
            L           Length; 0 if impossible, 1 if unambiguous, 2+ if ambiguous
             «2         Minimum of the above and 2 (sets ambiguous case to 2 no matter how many occurrences existed)
```

Comment: [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##JY9bSwJREMff@xThcw9mN8uHim5EQfQQPQWFSVaWQREEEu4WbVgRKLR211qNbpB22XPWKJjjHjx9izlfZDtbMAz/GWZ@85@lWCKx5XkyfcHM@ncU6RmUV9g10vOtVBvQlhGegTskBwPcQqpj7Y0bfJ8ZUBQVkVtu2PDxo6NTlJqDtQOsHXXXTfcTyS2zw2xvQGqf8AovwdQY0ge@76b7epBYm7zEdvnzuqiiQ9ZGg1KzN9jVBNzxbASJHUZyHa9X@qX@hCSjFlVvVpSVnoPSKH9Wh7jFKlBkdi8oRBHu3VzHEDrHSG9EVVlp2MIcb58Ea1hqdBvpl9SIz6G7qVjdXEB64rOpLgq8GvrR1YaoIDlE8jrN86Kgno9I7T202ijzyxmkxhTSvXA7lJTdPzvVefYFFJ3MPNzL9CnSHZZHp8DygxF4jym2r1i@Hyw3h9Rsghs3m1Ae3Kw6DZY/oULRjXF4DHnMUJXnBaLJQEtzIBQPtyU7fZVY/Mt@iv7raGsw3pUM/AI)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I am once again beaten by your superior understanding of chaining :P Thanks

Comment: [-68 bytes `“€ṡƥvẏÄhʠ!ịẈ?iḥẋỌ¹'ṅɦçç⁹.Sð$ṚṠȥṢK}/>œ;ỵZƤẓ}:;tÆṾḶj⁶ḄỵḋİʠUḊẈ½^ɲṆßṇµ⁶æḟɦ1¥©ḟþjHṀṪỤƑgạȥḂṾḞƓƑ@Ð⁾æƭVẈṣ’ḃ90Äḃ26ịØaØDW€¤;¶ŒṖe€€¢ȦƇL«2`](https://tio.run/##JY9LS0JRFIXn/Yq6BE2i1MAeQjVoENQsKmgQhEgqgpMIGghqppFBDyEsIh95r/QCCZSz7yUHZ@dB/Rfr/pHb0SZrr8XefJsVjyQSZ57npp/d7CeopsxT2Deciw6rU3CKsC/XYhAm7CKca0kzoIuBxU1uuhma2@HWNOgJVO2boPpWan61VwrBaR@oBuxSaiV0wnlQF6ITdzMdiJzeQRR/W8PqLsSVpsufw8E3KM8VUEG29RVbEJWB5ZemfNOOu/FNUBr0Dqeh7o5h1/QzkR1jX1RJ3a3zrZvpsqW@9jQQ9OqmHyHOl32c0yMQ1DW4fMTljX1dUTZCE7170ENEh1Gu9y1V2JYfAY8LOnueEU4as5NGILq0kAyOXCI21pGE/33Y74suJo0/)

Comment: And here’s a further -2 bytes: https://tio.run/##JY9LS0JRFIXn/Yq6BE2i1MAeQjVoENQsKmgQhFQqgpMIGghqppFBmRAWkY@8V3qBBMrZ95KDs/OQ/ot1/8jtaJO1F6zFt1mxw3j8zPPc1JOb@QDVlHkK@4azkUF1Ak4B9uVKFMKEXYBzLWkKdNG3uMlNN00zW9yaBD2Cqr8mqL6RnF3ulUJw2nuqAbuUXAqdcA7UhejE3HQHIqsziMJPa1DdhrjSdPm93/8C5bgCysu2brEFUelbfmnKV@24G1sHpUBvcBqqeAy7pp@JzAj7rEqquMq3brrLlvrc0UDQi5t6gDhf9HFWn0BQz@DyAZfXdvVE2QiN9e5A90eqqPKyvinfAx7ndeJ5RjhhTI8bgcjCXCI4dPHoSIcS/vdhvy8ynzD@AA

Comment: @hyper-neutrino hope it’s ok but I’ve now posted this as a separate answer

Comment: @NickKennedy Sorry, not sure how I missed your previous comments. Yes, that's fine, thanks for letting me know (+1 btw). -70 is... a lot and definitely worth posting in its own answer :P

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 117 bytes

Prints `-1` for impossible, `0` for unambiguous and `1` for ambiguous.

```
.œε.•B‚Δ—₅H^ƶƵXJ∍æ“ºl¦¯í-āмIõVÑK:Λ‘(·÷ΓKå<70'V∍∞±ζÚšË›¿ĆÅRÙΔu”ípā<À¿ýÌQмÛì‰Óǝ“§KhúγIÑËM`Êιš•#€SASõšøε`ì}˜žhS«såP}O<.±
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY7NS8JgHMf/lViHOtSwgozYpU7ZiF4GEkRhjWCCsEA6Co@CIVkH2Q7lS2CgHZqUxLSGJTzfzQ7Bg3/D7x9ZW10@fC7fFzN/epY9D4UbyoElXJnY4yaxurCJ2VQqb51MBhP3cJsqt@gSa3Ivx7v8Bb1FvzgdpeCmUVPXRYPY3TwfYigsFR0lmZhLRwmqPPC@GKAetFEl5vGxf4XyAe6FfUmshd6FX1TA@BifuNmfjtCAQ@wV1ncrnnpSDXjiLYUaqjsZXIuPoB3dm6WSo21ocKPWd@Fm4BR@msGXofHnPDp7hV1F5v0wPJJ0U1qYkZaNtRVzNbZc9o8x9H/XlxJG0pSOfwE)

```python
.œ              # push all partitions of the input
  ε      }      # map over the partitions:
   ...          #   push the table of valid parts (see below)
      s         #   swap to the current partition
       åP       #   test if every part is in the table
          O     # take the sum over all results
           <    # decrease by 1
            .±  # print the sign of this
```

##### Compressing the table

```python
.•B...š•                  # alphabet compressed string (contains 26 spaces)
        #                 # split on spaces
         €S               # split each string into a list of chars
           ASõš           # the characters of the alphabet with the empty string prepended
               øε`ì}      # zip alphabet with previous list and prepend matching characters
                    ˜     # flatten the list
                     žhS« # append the digits
```

[Try this part with step-by-step output!](https://tio.run/##XY67SgNBFIb7fYphLbSIYieIFrEQNVhoRMRCHHfH7MBmd8iMioUwCop4KcQU3iJEUAsjKhIvwQvsSbQQFp9hXiTOZhMF2/Of7/t/n@M5Sur1LiXPBpQ8CvNK5tXa@tDMx8NHeWpEbe7ChZInQcUNLoIbuO6srn6/DEN5EvZSveGxkgcdwSM8hvspOO/r6W6f1ITaPA3uwgc4qhVhW8lK8F7dgPVxOAzzC0oW4JpVV/tABu/wCjtj3y9wDCUlb2H/sxBVXaYcqIT3w7AH26OzsBU@14p6nmEmXebgOSKQ5WdZjnBObMRFjnqZXjPRbxhthmmkmUsF8j3EGbYIjwO1Vkr/ZgRbThND1BM@wsilXDPzyHJwrokk01CuFTU04ZDGHVuC5Hj0JfQFt6YsUeE0LiTLxHLLq9cx4tnEjmXwFJZnobSiddOU/YP17yL1F3i8Ant2i0ZZLCwn0v31x76vE20adLEQxGuUR2gc1d6cdHCl4yRrOKLUphkqmqhpJuAWXhP1@g8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 124 bytes

```
“€ṡƥvẏÄhʠ!ịẈ?iḥẋỌ¹'ṅɦçç⁹.Sð$ṚṠȥṢK}/>œ;ỵZƤẓ}:;tÆṾḶj⁶ḄỵḋİʠUḊẈ½^ɲṆßṇµ⁶æḟɦ1¥©ḟþjHṀṪỤƑgạȥḂṾḞƓƑ@Ð⁾æƭVẈṣ’ḃ90Äḃ26ịØaØDW€¤;
ŒṖfƑƇ¢L«2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY9LS0JRFIXn/Yq6BE2i1MAeQjVoENQsKmgQhFQqgpMIGghqppFBmRAWkY@8V3qBBMrZ95KDs/OQ/ot1/8jtaJO1F6zFt1mxw3j8zPPc1JOb@QDVlHkK@4azkUF1Ak4B9uVKFMKEXYBzLWkKdNG3uMlNN00zW9yaBD2Cqr8mqL6RnF3ulUJw2nuqAbuUXAqdcA7UhejE3HQHIqsziMJPa1DdhrjSdPm93/8C5bgCysu2brEFUelbfmnKV@24G1sHpUBvcBqqeAy7pp@JzAj7rEqquMq3brrLlvrc0UDQi5t6gDhf9HFWn0BQz@DyAZfXdvVE2QiN9e5A90eqqPKyvinfAx7ndeJ5RjhhTI8bgcjCXCI4dPHoSIcS/vdhvy8ynzD@AA)

A set of links that takes a string argument and returns 0 for impossible, 1 for a single valid interpretation and 2 for ambiguous.

Loosely based on [@hyper-neutrino’s answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226852/42248), but mostly rewritten.